# Question on union of sets with nontrivial homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $n,k$ be integers such that $n\ge k\ge 0$. Let $U_1\subseteq U_2\subseteq ...$ be a sequence of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for each $i$, $H_k(U_i)$ is nontrivial. Then would $H_k(\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}U_i)$ be also nontrivial?

Comment: First of all if $U_i$ is an ipen set in $\mathbb R^n$ then $H_n(U_i)=0$.

Comment: Yes, it is; the main problem is when n>k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $n = 2$, and for $i \ge 0$ consider the circle $S_i = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid (x-i)^2 + y^2 = 1/2 \}$. Finally let
$$U_i = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \bigcup_{j \ge i} S_j.$$
Then $H_1(U_i)$ is nontrivial for all $i$, but $\bigcup_{i \ge 0} U_i = \mathbb{R}^2$ has trivial $H_1$.